# Is every projective variety the zero set of a system equations which are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Is every projective variety the zero set of a system equations which are homogeneous polynomials **of the same degree**?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. Does your definition of variety require the ideal be prime?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor . Yes

Comment: It is perfectly clear to anyone with even a modest  appreciation of algebraic geometry that this question is perfectly legitimate and even interesting. It should not have been closed and it is shocking to see a beginner receive such an unpleasant welcome on this site. The question should be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can assume that all defining equations have the same degree! Here is the trick:
Suppose that the variety $V\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ is defined by $s$ homogeneous polynomials $f_i(x_0,\cdots,x_n)\in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$
of  degrees $\deg f_i=d_i$, namely $$V=Z(f_i\vert i=1,\cdots,s)$$ Now let $d=\max d_i$. The trick is then to realize that each equation $f_i=0$ is equivalent to the system of $n+1$ equations $$f_i\cdot x_j^{d-d_i}=0 \;(j=0,\cdots,n)$$ We thus see that $V$ is defined by the system of $s(n+1)$ equations $f_i\cdot x_j^{d-d_i}=0$ **all of degree d:**
$$V=Z(f_i\cdot x_j^{d-d_i}\vert i=1,\cdots17\;;j=0,\cdots,n)$$
(And note that this trick  works whether "irreducible" is part of your definition of variety or not.)

Comment: Suppose that the variety $V\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ is defined by $s$ homogeneous polynomials $f_i(x_0,\cdots,x_n)\in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ . Why $f_i$ is homogeneous ? I think we define variety for $Z(f)$ for every arbitrary function but you assume that $f$ is homogeneous function.

Comment: No, varieties in projective space **can only be defined by homogeneous polynomials**. For example:  does $x^2-y$ vanish at $[3:9]$? Apparently, yes. Does that polynomial vanish at $[1:3]$? Apparently, no. But this is nonsense since $[3:9]=[1:3]\in \mathbb P^2_k$. This contradiction arises because the polynomial  $x^2-y$ is **not homogeneous** and saying that it vanishes at a point is meaningless.

Comment: What is mean of $f_i\cdot x_j^{d-d_i} \;(j=0,\cdots,n)$ ? It's mean that $f_i \times x_j^{d-d_i}  $?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: So we add a solution to zero set of $f_i$ for example if $f_i(0) \neq 0$  then $0$ is not in zero set of $f_i$ but $0$ is always in zero set of $f_i x_j$ is this true?